# I want my font sizes to change responsively. Is javascript the best way?

Tags: javascript, css

If I hava all my font sizes in ems, and then use javascript to change the css rule determining font-size of the body (which will be in px) surely this will result in text that grows with a widening, percentage-based grid?

Apparently, changing css rules is tricky and doesn't support legacy versions of some browsers (guess which one), but if I embed my body rules right on the page, will that make things cross compliant?

Comment: Definitely you [can change a CSS rule](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17454470/1169519) also in those anonymous "legacy browsers".

Comment: You could use some kind of finished [media query library](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) for earlier browsers. Still uses Javascript, but saves you the hassle of writing/testing it yourself.

Comment: ypu can use the font-size  in em  like font-size:1em  or  in %  like  font-size:5%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `font-size` in em like `font-size:1em` or in % like `font-size:5%`

try to put the  css in

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 800px) 
{  css   }
```

according to  device width like  ipad   and for the  iphone you can change that

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) 
{   here is css  }
```

so that  you able to see your design perfectly st these resolution

Comment: Just to add some explanation to the answer, by setting your font to 1em you set it to the default size of the user's system, one of the downsides is if the user has his set to a high value due to being visually impaired.

Comment: Looks like OP is concerning about legacy browsers too, media queries are not supported in older IEs.

Comment: i am useing and working well in all browsers  which version you are useing @Teemu

Comment: Several versions and browsers when I'm testing some code, and especially when I'm creating cross-browser code ; ). Anyway, [Media Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was introduced in version 9 in IE.

Comment: its also working  fine in ie8 here and its for the mobile devices like i pad and ihone  and the browser our normal css  will work fine   @Teemu

Comment: Where it's working, probably a missing link in your comment? Please don't trust emulation modes in IE9+, when testing code for older IEs, they are not accurate enough...

Comment: ok  i will study deeply on this   i think you have  lot of knowlege and experince  thanks@teemu