# Get posX and posY of background-position in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, parsing

If I assume that the background position will always be in the format:

`0px 0px; or 10px 11px;` So, **number**px **number**px.

How can I get both the x position and the y position in Javascript?

Comment: Do you want the units as well, or just the numbers?

Comment: I am looking for both units and numbers. Is there any JS function that would tell you that?

Comment: Is it assigned via class? If so, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19458615/961695

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

And CSS:

```
div {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff url(http://placekitten.com/300/300) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

The following JavaScript works:

```
var demo = document.getElementById('demo'),
    _tmp = window.getComputedStyle(demo,null).backgroundPosition.trim().split(/\s+/),
    positions = {
        'left' : _tmp[0],
        'top' : _tmp[1]
    };
console.log(positions, positions.left, positions.top);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wtdbu/).

The above approach does require a browser that supports `window.getComputedStyle()` (obviously), and `trim()` (though that could be replaced with a [`replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wtdbu/1/)).

To get access to the units, and numbers, independently I'd suggest creating other objects within the overall object to hold those numbers, and units:

```
var demo = document.getElementById('demo'),
    _tmp = window.getComputedStyle(demo,null).backgroundPosition.trim().split(/\s+/),
    positions = {
        'left' : _tmp[0],
        'top' : _tmp[1],
        'numbers' : {
            'left' : parseFloat(_tmp[0]),
            'top' : parseFloat(_tmp[1])
        },
        'units' : {
            'left' : _tmp[0].replace(/\d+/,''),
            'top' : _tmp[1].replace(/\d+/,'')
        }
    };
console.log(positions, positions.left, positions.top, positions.numbers.left, positions.numbers.top, positions.units.left, positions.units.top);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wtdbu/2).

As to what would happen if there was no `background-position` set? Well, why not try that, with the following CSS:

```
div {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/300);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In Chromium it seems that you get the default `background-position` of `0% 0%` (and corresponding numbers and units): [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wtdbu/3/).

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirect=no).
- [`String.parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).
- [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. However, if I wanted to get the values and units separately, how could I do it? I mean, if I needed to know the value to do some calculus and then the units?

Comment: Also, what would happen if the element does not have a background-position attribute? What would this do: window.getComputedStyle(demo,null).backgroundPosition

Comment: See the updates, I think I've answered those questions adequately?