# Blank entry when tried to return background position value in chome console

Tags: javascript

I have a div with a background image positioned at X 0px and Y 0px position. Now I want to return this values in a console.log, but the console shows me a blank entry. I tried with alert and is the same.

Why is this happening?

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')[0];

console.log(myDiv.style.backgroundPositionY);
```

```css
.myDiv{
  width:200px; height:200px;
  background:blue;
  background-image:url(http://www.shunvmall.com/data/out/141/46916550-landscape-pictures.jpeg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:0px 0px;
 background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: .style only provides the inline style values applied to the element. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `style` object on an element only reflects the styles **directly** applied to the element. Styles applied by classes do not show there. To get those, use `getComputedStyle` (standard) or `currentStyle` (IE-specific):

Standard:

```
console.log(getComputedStyle(myDiv).backgroundPositionY);
```

IE-specific:

```
console.log(myDiv.currentStyle.backgroundPositionY);
```

Example of standard:

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')[0];

console.log(getComputedStyle(myDiv).backgroundPositionY);
```

```css
.myDiv{
  width:200px; height:200px;
  background:blue;
  background-image:url(http://www.shunvmall.com/data/out/141/46916550-landscape-pictures.jpeg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:0px 0px;
 background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this method.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below

```
var divElem = document.querySelector('.myDiv');
style = getComputedStyle(divElem)
console.log(style.backgroundPositionY);
```

Codepen -https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MmEjjr?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

The following JavaScript works:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')[0],
    _tmp =     window.getComputedStyle(myDiv,null).backgroundPosition.trim().split(/\s+/),
    positions = {
        'left' : _tmp[0],
        'top' : _tmp[1]
    };
console.log(positions, positions.left, positions.top);
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505142/get-posx-and-posy-of-background-position-in-javascript)