# Changing stylesheets after DOM is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my HTML I have a `div`:

```
<div id="devicelayout">
    Some text here
</div>
```

and corresponding CSS:

```
#devicelayout
{
    width:1078px;
}
```

Once my page is loaded, how do I change the rules of CSS `#devicelayout`?

Comment: Change the rules? Can you give more detail? I mean you could define rules in a class, and add that class to the element. Or you can put styles directly on an element. Are you sure you actually need what you're asking for?

Comment: Do you use jquery or plain javascript as we can suppose from tags that you added ?

Comment: i want to change the definition of css selector #devicelayout

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17454470/1169519), maybe you get some ideas.

Comment: jquery or javascript both

Comment: I'd be tempted to override the property values in the stylesheet with local values in a style attribute on the element. Modifying the stylesheet itself may well trigger a recaculate and repaint for the entire page. This is a non trivial operation and would be bad for performance, especially in a loop or as part of a rapidly repeating operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to change css styles of the element you can directly assign a different class to it or change css properties of the element using JQuery using

`$("#devicelayout").css("property", "value")`

or

`$("#devicelayout").addClass("newClass")`

Or if you want to change css rules then try modifying stylesheet rules at `document.styleSheets` object. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452726/manipulating-css-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#devicelayout").css("width","500px");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#devicelayout').css("attributeName","attributeValue");
})
```

Here you have some more info about using css function: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery as a solution for this... put all the css changes you want your #devicelayout to happen after page load into a css file for example devicelayout.css. then in your script tag (ofcourse after you include the jquery library) add this code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   if($("#devicelayout").size()>0){ /*Check if the id "#devicelayout" exists within your DOM*/

  $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='devicelayout.css' type='text/css' />")); /*if true, the new <link> element is appended to the <head> element */   }
});
```

This will also let you change the css of a number of ids after page load, not just one. hopefully this helps