# detecting and hiding dynamically creating div after a specific seconds (not onclick)

Tags: html, dynamic, hide

i have a dynamically generating div which is not in the time of loading. It is generating later in the document. So how can i target that div and hide it after specific time. The div is as follows:

```
<div class="message-sent">Your Message has been sent</div>
```

Important: I refer so many articles but everyone is talking about 'onclick'. I don't want click event. I just want hide this div when it is appearing in the docuemnt. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should try looking into the setTimeout function. 
Also if that div is the only member of the DOM-tree that has that class, use an ID. It's better IMO. 
Anyway, assuming you want to hide every member of the `message-sent`-class,
it goes something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.message-sent').hide();
}, 2000)
```

In which the `2000`is the variable that indicates the time (milliseconds)

Comment: hi friend...this code works with already existing div. But in my case '.message-sent' div is created after a long time after clicking a button.

Comment: Could you add the code where you dynamically create the div?

Comment: if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo '<div class="message-sent">Your Message has been 
    sent</div>';}

once my mail is success with php, then this div is generating. But i can't make hide this after a specific time with jQuery as this is not existing previously in document.

Comment: If I'm correct, CSS is added no matter when your element gets added. So if you were to add a line in your CSS like this: `.message-sent{ display: none }`After that, you change that line of code. I don't know exactly how to do it, but I found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452726/manipulating-css-with-javascript I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

1. you can add a style display:none.
2. you can add the style after time out (3000ms) like so:

   ```
   setTimeout(function(){ 
     document.getElementsByClassName("message-sent")[0].style.display="none"; 
   }, 3000);
   ```

note: it is better if you use an id instead of a class to identify your div.

Comment: hi friend this is not working. You code is good for already existing div. But for dynamically generating div, it is not working. The 'message-sent' div is not existing in the document on load. it is generating later on click of a submit button.

Comment: Well if u call the function after the click event then the div should be there later.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DOMNodeInserted`,

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
 var element = document.getElementsByClassName("message-sent"); // get all elements with class message-sent
 var lastchild = element[element.length - 1]; // get the last one (others are hidden)
 if(lastchild != null){
    lastchild.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // set visibility to hidden
 }
});
```

Working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qcq0cxnu/2/)

Hope helps,